# Combine 2 android projects into one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have 2 android project 1 and 2. I need to create one screen with button A and B. If i click A screen it should invoke 1 project same if i click B it should invoke 2. But it should create one apk. Can you please suggest your ideas.

Comment: Look up how to make a Gradle multi module project

Comment: I didn't use gradle. Give me any sample link please

Comment: You have the Andrea Studio tag, therefore you should have a Gradle project. If you don't, then I'm not sure what good a link would do

Answer (score -1):

very recommend to use the repo to handle your require **safely and easily**: [Jacksgong/android-project-combine](https://github.com/Jacksgong/android-project-combine), which just mock an wrapper env project to let you maintain multiple projects on one Android Studio window.